# My express server is getting a lot of get request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

i have a server running express on an EC2 AWS instance. When I run my server, I instantly get many get requests to the root of the server, this causes my server to start to crash. I have Helmet enabled on my express server. any idea what i can do to avoid this. I have access enabled through a reverse proxu with Apache and I run everything on Ubuntu 20.04.
Also on my server, I have mail services running and the website with mysql

Jaime

Comment: There's nothing in your question that would indicate where the GET requests are coming from. Are you logging these requests so you can see where they are from?

Comment: Yes.  I can see when i running the server in dev  mode and Aldo i can see it in the  listen of established connections in ubuntu.  All the connections are coming from differents ip adresses

Comment: From MySQL Command Prompt, post results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%error%'; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%error%';  please.